# What is the cleanest way in swift to use an optional in a function parameter when nil should return a specific default value?

Tags: swift, parameters, option-type

I need to unwrap the optional and use it as a parameter to the function. If the optional is nil, then I need to default to a specific value.

Is there a shorter/cleaner way to code this example?

```
func iTake(aNonOptional nonOptionalInt: Int) -> Float {
    // do something with nonOptionalInt
    return Float(nonOptionalInt) * 0.125
}

var anOptionalInt: Int?
let aSpecificDefaultReturnValue: Float = 0.99

let result: Float
if let aNonOptionalInt = anOptionalInt {
    result = iTake(aNonOptional: aNonOptionalInt)
} else {
    result = aSpecificDefaultReturnValue
}
```

My actual use-case is more complicated, but this is the idea.

The function can't be rewritten, but can the `if let` be written in a better way?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var anOptionalInt: Int?
let aSpecificDefaultReturnValue: Float = 0.99
let result = anOptionalInt.map { iTake(aNonOptional: $0) } ?? aSpecificDefaultReturnValue
```

You can use the fact that the Swift `Optional` enum has a `map` function, and couple it with the nil coalescing operator:

- `Optional.map` looks inside your optional 'box' and (if it finds something in the box) uses the transform you supply to alter your value, or ignores the transform if you have nothing inside the box (i.e. a `nil`).
- The nil coalescing operator `??` basically says 'return everything left of me if that thing is not-nil, otherwise return everything right of me'.

Comment: The *nil coalescing operator* unwraps the left hand side if it isn't `nil` or uses the right hand side if it is.

Comment: how do you mean 'unwraps' @vacawama?

Comment: The result of the `map` is an optional because if `anOptionalInt` is `nil`, the `map` will return `nil`.  So the type returned from the `map` is an optional.  Since `iTake` returns a `Float`, the result of the `map` will be a `Float?`.  The nil coalescing operator either unwraps that `Float?` making it a `Float` or it substitutes the `aSpecificDefaultReturnValue`.

Comment: Thanks for the explantation of the term ;-)

Comment: this is very good, no forced unwrap, no variable used twice. but the map is a bit unintuitive. perhaps if I use this pattern enough, it will become second hand. let's see if there are any other nifty answers. thanks for this!

Comment: We found the same, regarding the use of `map`, when we first moved to Swift. I can tell you that it definitely does become second nature, like any other keyword which abstracts away a more complex concept.

Comment: What if I extend optional to have the `unwrap` function do `map`    
`extension Optional {  
    func unwrap<U>(_ transform: (Wrapped) throws -> U) rethrows -> U? {  
        return try map(transform)  
    }  
}`  
That way the name makes more sense maybe? This may be a bit picky. What do you think?

Comment: I get where you're going @Andy, but I reckon `map` is such a baked in name/symbol to the language (and to many others) that you may as well just use that. Using `map` on an `Optional` actually makes a lot of sense when you consider `map` as a concept in its full functional glory: a thing which takes something out of a box and transforms it.

Comment: @sjwarner yeah, I have to change my idea of map. I was introduced to it grouped with reduce and filter, but map stands alone. optional doesn't implement reduce or filter, which makes sense. thanks for this additional info.

Answer (score -2):

You could also do it like that:

```
let result: Float = (anOptionalInt != nil) ? iTake(aNonOptional: anOptionalInt!) : aSpecificDefaultReturnValue
```

If `anOptionalInt` is not nil, the iTake function is called taking as argument the unwrapped value of the `anOptionalInt` variable (force unwrapping here is ok, since we've checked already whether it's nil or not). If it's nil, then keep the default value as the result.

Comment: this is good, intuitive and easy to understand.  but there is the ´!´ forced unwrap and the variable name twice. thanks for this.

Comment: the force unwrap is completely safe since object was checked for nil on the left side of this tertiary statement.

Comment: yes, but when you later change the code, you have to remember to change both variables, or it can cause a crash! and the compiler won't help you. I try to avoid these if possible. @Augie

Comment: @Andy What do you mean by saying that you have to change both variables when you change the code? You mean the variable name? Xcode will warn you about that (it'll show errors). Also, if you change the type of the `anOptionalInt` variable, or if you stop having it as Optional, Xcode again won’t accept the current code. Please provide us with some more information about it so it’s easier to come up with a better solution if exists.

Comment: sorry. there is no compiler check to make sure that ´anOptionalInt!´ won't crash. your code checks that the variable is not nil before executing that code, but that is not checked by the compiler. if someone comes later and changes the 'anOptionalInt' to pass a different variable to the function, they also have to remember to change the variable in the part where you check to see if it's nil '(anOptionalInt != nil)'. there will be no compiler reminders to do this.

Comment: My experience with swift so far has shown Andy's thinking to be correct: if you have to use a force unwrap, you're basically saying to the compiler 'don't worry, I know better than you, you can trust me in this case', but as Andy points out, there is no guarantee that your assertion will continue to be true after multiple refactors. Using an alternate method of expressing your intention, where you lean on the compiler to decide what is true or not, will be safer in the long run. I have benefited from this approach too many times!

Comment: @sjwarner Personally, I never force unwrap optionals, I always use `if let` when dealing with them. But since Andy doesn't want to use `if let` and wants short code, my answer was the shortest I could think of. I can't understand why he doesn't want to use `if let` and trade safety with shorter code. And instead of down voting, please suggest a better solution than mine and according to Andy's requirements. No need to provide all this theory, we all know it. Provide code.

Comment: @Gabriel: I did provide code, see my answer! And while you may know 'all this theory', others don't. As for the downvote, that's how SO works right? Your code is suboptimal - I wouldn't want my team using it, so I'll use the only two tools available to me on SO to stop others from using it: a downvote and good explanation as to why.